# Apple(Fructose) and Uric Acid

Tags: fructose, uric-acid

Recently I've been reading about fruits to be consumed when you have high level of uric acid in blood. One thing I found contradicting is most of the reputed websites mention Apple is good to lower uric acid and they also mention Fructose rich food should be avoided. I just googled and found that Apple is rich in fructose, then is it good for people with high uric acid?
Can anyone shed some light onto it.

Few references where I found Apple helps in managing Uric acid and gout.
https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/diet/20-foods-to-keep-your-uric-acid-at-normal-levels/articleshow/20585546.cms

https://www.livestrong.com/article/533102-apples-gout/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about nutrition and diet are on topic here only if they're directly related to medical treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A medium apple (182 g) can contain ~10 grams of fructose ([NutritionData](https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1809/2)).

**1) The claims that apples lower blood uric acid are not supported by evidence.**

[Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/diet/20-foods-to-keep-your-uric-acid-at-normal-levels/articleshow/20585546.cms) says that apples, because they are high in malic acid, can lower blood uric acid and [Livestrong](https://www.livestrong.com/article/533102-apples-gout/) says that apples have this effect, because they are high in vitamin C, but neither of them provide any evidence for that.

**2) Apples increase blood uric acid shortly after ingestion.**

In the study [The effects of apples and apple juice on acute plasma uric acid concentration (AJCN, 2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29529161), the ingestion of apples with 26.7 g fructose in total increased blood uric acid (measured 30 minutes after ingestion).

**3) Frequent consumption of apples have been associated with an increased risk of gout.**

The study [Soft drinks, fructose consumption, and the risk of gout in men (BMJ, 2008)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2234536/) found an association, but not a direct cause-effect relationships, between high apple consumption and gout:

> Other major contributors to fructose intake such as total fruit juice
>   or fructose rich fruits (apples and oranges) were also associated with
>   a higher risk of gout.

**4) Moderate fructose intake does not increase uric acid levels in blood and the risk of cardiovascular disease.**

[Fructose Intake, Serum Uric Acid, and Cardiometabolic Disorders: A Critical Review (Nutrients, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5409734/):

> In summary, a specific causal link between fructose consumption,
>   hyperuricemia, and CVD has not yet been established. There is an
>   association between UA and established cardiovascular risk factors,
>   and there is a limit to how much population-based studies can adjust
>   for confounding variables. As such, **it is not yet possible to
>   conclude that fructose intake is the main contributor to an increase
>   in blood UA,** and that this detrimentally affects vascular health.
>
> ...*hypercaloric* supplementation of control diets with **fructose (+35%
>   excess energy) at extreme doses (213–219 g/day)** significantly
>   increased serum UA compared with the control diets alone.

**5) Fructose intake that does not contribute to excessive calorie intake does not increase the risk of gout.**

[The Effects of Fructose Intake on Serum Uric Acid Vary among Controlled Dietary Trials (The Journal of Nutrition, 2012)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3327749/):

> These analyses do not support a uric acid-increasing effect of
>   *isocaloric* fructose intake in nondiabetic and diabetic participants.
>   *Hypercaloric* fructose intake may, however, increase uric acid
>   concentrations.

**6) Fruits and gout**

[The effects of fruit consumption in patients with hyperuricaemia or gout (Rheumatology, 2019)](https://academic.oup.com/rheumatology/article/58/7/1133/5475481):

> Fruits contain fructose, but not all studies suggest they increase the
>   risk for gout. Several reasons appear to account for this, including
>   the relatively small amount of fructose in an individual fruit and the
>   association with substances in fruits that slow absorption (e.g.
>   fibre), stimulate excretion (vitamin C) or block fructose metabolic
>   effects (epicatechin)...In addition, people
>   who ingest high amounts of fruit are often reducing their intake of
>   refined sugars, so that overall fructose intake may be low.

**In summary,** apples do not decrease but increase the levels of uric acid in blood, but an apple or two a day (10-20 g fructose) is unlikely to increase the risk of gout or other conditions related to blood uric acid levels.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed study, this is truly an eye opener that only trust info that backs scientific study.